# Hosting a Color.argb(a,r,g,b) inside a byte without losing information

Tags: java, byte

The question is pretty much inside the title.

I want to host inside a byte ,a color without losing any sort of information, keeping in mind that the Color.argb is actually an int.

```
Byte colorToSave;

colorToSave = Color.argb(255, 255,0, 100);
```

As far as I know this is pretty much impossible, but perhaps someone found a nice workaround.

Comment: 1. Don't confuse Byte and byte. 2. You can't store 32 bits in 8 bits without losing information. 3. Why can't you use an int?

Comment: Eventually I will use an int ,but it was strictly for optimization ,nothing else.

Anyways,all in all, it's impossible,right?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't make sense to compress an int to a byte just for optimization.

Comment: I send the value ,so the point was to send as little information as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible - the core of Color.argb is a number of bitwise operations -

```
alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
```

So if we break it down with your values (255,255,0,100) you can see that you can see the precision loss -

```
int alpha  = 255;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(alpha));
int red = 255;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(red));
int green = 0;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(green));
int blue = 100;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(blue));
int argb = 255<<24 | 255 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 100;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(argb));
byte argbbyte = (byte) argb;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(argbbyte));
```

Producing an output -

```
11111111
11111111
0
1100100
11111111111111110000000001100100
1100100
```

The final part of the output is casting the int to a byte which shows we return the color for blue